# Getting a expection when i build my spring boot application in eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot

**Here's the code**

```
package com.letsstartcoding.springbootrestapiexample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class EmployeeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**This is the exception that is occurring when i run the particular code above. Any help will be appreciated**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.letsstartcoding.springbootrestapiexample.EmployeeApplication.main(EmployeeApplication.java:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the problem with migration String Boot to JDK 9. Spring Boot Dev Tools v1.5 is not compatible with Java 9 [per this bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9381). The problem was fixed in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5.

Check [Spring Boot plugin failure](https://blog.frankel.ch/migrating-to-java-9/1/) section.